# Is it possible to override UserManager.GetRoles to return RoleId as well

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm using the default MVC Authentication. 
In the AspNetRoles table I have

```
Id  Name
1   Administrator
2   Moderator
3   User
```

The UserManager.GetRoles(UserId) would then return only the role name. Is it possible to also get the Id or should I use some kind of LINQ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way get Role ID like 
`UserManager.GetRoles(UserId)` but 
you can get role Id by using this LINQ

```
    var roleId = _dbContext.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName).Id;
```